ObjectBox does not generate after flutter upgrade
i have upgraded flutter version to 3.19.2 & no when i run
flutter pub run build_runner build
i get this error:
[SEVERE] objectbox_generator:generator on lib/$lib$:
Unknown relation backlink source
but this worked before and i have not changed the backlink relation
i have tried deleting the objectbox.g and object-model.json but do not get generated again

The error message should tell you which field is the problem. Then double-check that the relation it refers to actually exists with that name. If that won't resolve your issue, please submit an error report including a code example on the ObjectBox Dart issue tracker: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues
